# How to pass a parent id (via foreignkey) if the child form is located on the same template as the parent form?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django and I am trying to write a "reply" code for a comment. Currently, when a user clicks the button "reply", the link takes them to a new page, which allows me to pass the parent comment_id to the reply as a foreign key. How can I place the "reply" form on the same page as the comment? I apologize if my question is entirely stupid, I am just learning! Thank you!

My current code for the "reply" is:

--> how can I pass the comment_id to the reply if the reply form is on the same page as the "comment"?

```
def reply(request, comment_id):     
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=comment_id)
    form_reply = ReplyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form_reply.is_valid():
            a_comment = form_reply.save(commit=False)
            a_comment.comment = comment
            a_comment.save()
            return redirect('two_forms')

    all_replies = Reply.reply_objects.all()
    return render(request, 'reply.html', {'form_reply': form_reply, 'all_replies': all_replies, })
```

I tried to place this code on the same template as the "comment" but then the comment_id messes with the url of the comment page and gives an error.